# Move rarely used files to another storage location (with nextcloud)

Tags: storage, cloud

Lets say there is a NextCloud instance, that stores data on the local filesystem. Though the software is not that important, as I would like to implement it on OS level, to have the best performance.
I know that there are a lot of files that are rarely used.
Since I have to back them up regularly and also fast storage (read SSD) space is more expensive, I would rather have the files that are rarely accessed moved to a cheaper storage.
Also I would like to consider a different backup strategy for those files, since they rarely change.

Ideally the storage location itself (lets say /storage) does not change at all for the system itself access-vise, so that I do not have to do anything fancy with the software that uses it.

The filesystem would be ext4 Filesystem, if that is of any importance.
OS: Linux (Debian to be precise, I have a little flex on that one, though. If avoidable, I do not want to change to some OpenBSD distro)

I could not find anything about move less accessed files automatically.
Maybe I am just using the wrong search terms :D

Is there such a solution or are there ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: Happens automatically, called cache. You'd have to have really odd requirements (say, really large files) for the cheapest solution not to be adding a bunch of those sweet sweet GiBs of RAM.

Comment: And if your backup strategy does not automatically gain some capacity & speed benefit from most files not changing (*incremental backups*), you should switch to a backup toolset that does; all the good ones do.

Comment: To which 'caching' are you referring here? Of course drive caching does a little bit of that, but I am talking files that are lets say two weeks old (just an example number). I do not see how RAM would solve this problem though. I do not want to run a ram drive for any of the above. Could you be a little more precise, please? Maybe name some examples?
 - My backup does incremental versions of files. I just wanted full backups to get faster.